# Where/When can I find Xur in Destiny tower and what does he sell?

Tags: destiny

I've heard many people talk of an exotic vendor named Xur who only comes on the weekends, but I couldn't find him anywhere in the tower, and he wasn't on the map either this weekend. I was wondering if someone could just clear this up. Also, does he always have the same stuff, is it random, or is it a cycle of some sort.

Comment: If you need complete information you can check [PlanetDestiny](http://planetdestiny.com/where-xur-april2/), they make an article every week with he's location and gear (plus give recommendations).

Comment: Check out [Xurday.com](http://Xurday.com) and use the button on the top left to see where he is on the map. Very useful site.

Answer (score 2):

Those people are indeed correct in saying that Xur can be found in the tower on the weekends. He is present at the tower **between 9 am Friday and 9 am Sunday** GMT (apply your local time difference to this). As to his location, it is changed every week, he can spawn in either of the three wings of the tower but a quick search should find you in his presence. The loot that Xur sells is also *randomized* each week and you should be able to find out his inventory for the week from a number of websites, I use this one [here](https://downtoday.co.uk/destiny-xur-location/). Start saving those strange coins!